# Issue putting python output in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When I print the output of my code it's all perfect, but when I try to append it to a pandas `dataframe` it only takes the last value of `x`.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something but i am kind of lost, I tried putting this in my for loop:

```
text['Answer_readability']= x
print(text['Answer_readability'].head)
```

It doesn't work, because it gives me a `dataframe` with the last value 100 times in stead of each value 1 time.

This is my code:

```
og_text = 'D:\javafornltk.csv'
text = pd.read_csv(og_text, dtype=str, nrows=100)
answer_body = text['Answer Body']
for row in answer_body:
  if '<p>' and '</p>' in row:
    if row.isalpha:
      if not '<code>' in row:
        if not 'href' in row:
          endrow = re.sub('<.+?>', '', row)
          x = textstat.flesch_reading_ease(endrow)
          print(x)
  text['Answer_readability']= x
print(text['Answer_readability'].head)
```

It gives me this output:

```
1     70.13
2     70.13
3     70.13
4     70.13
5     70.13
6     70.13
7     70.13
8     70.13
9     70.13
10    70.13
11    70.13
12    70.13
13    70.13
14    70.13
15    70.13
16    70.13
17    70.13
18    70.13
19    70.13
20    70.13
21    70.13
22    70.13
23    70.13
24    70.13
25    70.13
26    70.13
27    70.13
28    70.13
29    70.13
```

But I'd like it printed as:

```
79.77
-7.7
71.78
58.62
53.88
34.26
24.79
71.85
-40.86
44.24
44.14
57.27
-8.04
59.84
10.56
73.0
76.22
49.52
59.98
65.56
46.44
47.8
78.28
85.69
54.56
61.7
38.66
25.8
29.87
-59.47
62.34
80.62
49.49
40.35
70.13
```

Comment: I've made an edit to fix your formatting and indentation, please double check that it's correct

Comment: The issue is with your line `text['Answer_readability']= x`. In your loop, that bit of code assigns every value in that column to `x` every time the loop runs, including the last time. Instead, try creating a list to contain all the values `container_list=[]`, and append to it in the loop `container_list.append(x)`, then at the end assign it to the column `text['Answer_readability'] = container_list`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i have altered my code in: `code` for row in answer_body:
`code` container_list= [] and at the end:   endrow = re.sub('<.+?>', '', row)
                                                                    x = textstat.flesch_reading_ease(endrow)
                                                                    container_list.append(x)
                                                                    text['Answer_readability'] = container_list `code` but it gives me an error: because container_list is only 1 value long. I think i misplaced the statements...

Comment: Unfortunately I can;t test as I don;t have you data to work with, but see my answer below and comment if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you! made my day and it worked perfectly. I'll accept your answer as the best one. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding my comment above into a full answer:
Your line `text['Answer_readability']= x` in your loop assigns every value in that column to be whatever `x` is in that iteration. You can solve this by appending the x values to a container, and then assigning the column after the loop completes. (There are other solutions that involve iterating through the dataframe, but IMO this is the simplest)

```
og_text = 'D:\javafornltk.csv'
text = pd.read_csv(og_text, dtype=str, nrows=100)
answer_body = text['Answer Body']

container_list=[]

for row in answer_body:
    if '<p>' and '</p>' in row:
        if row.isalpha:
            if not '<code>' in row:
                if not 'href' in row:
                    endrow = re.sub('<.+?>', '', row)
                    x = textstat.flesch_reading_ease(endrow)
                    print(x)
                    container_list.append(x)
text['Answer_readability']=container_list
print(text['Answer_readability'].head())
```